# How to find out if a linux machine was connected to a certain wireless access point ?(wireless connection history)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I am trying to find out a piece of log that states that a machine was connected to a certain wireless access point sometime in the past. Where exactly does linux store this information.(some file in /var/log/ ?) or some other place?

Comment: In my case, it was in /var/log/syslog file. 
It can also be in specific wireless configuration related files inside /var/log/

Answer (score 0):

You are able find logs in /var/log/syslog file. Also you can find kernel logs through dmesg.